# ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected convolution2d_2 to have shape (None, 26, 26, 64) but got array with shape (250, 227, 227, 1)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'm using Keras with Tensorflow as backend , here is my code:

```
#image loading and preprocessing
import os
from PIL import Image as Image
import numpy as np

#files is a list of images
files = [os.path.join('Save', file_i)
 for file_i in os.listdir('Save')
 if '.jpg' in file_i]

imgs = []
for image in files:
    img = Image.open(image) 
    img = img.resize((227,227),Image.BILINEAR)
    img = img.convert('L')

    img = np.asarray(img)

    array = img.astype('float32')
    array /= 255        
    imgs.append(array)  

imgs = np.asarray(imgs)

The_data = imgs.reshape(imgs.shape[0], 227, 227,1)
The_data = The_data.reshape(10, 25, 227, 227, 1)

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D,Deconvolution2D
from keras.layers.convolutional_recurrent import ConvLSTM2D
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.wrappers import TimeDistributed
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt



model = Sequential()
#2 Convolution layer


model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(128, 11, 11 , border_mode='same', subsample = (4,4)), input_shape=(None,227, 227, 1)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(64, 5, 5, border_mode='same', subsample = (2,2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(ConvLSTM2D(nb_filter=64, nb_row=3, nb_col=3,
                   border_mode='same', return_sequences=True)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(TimeDistributed(ConvLSTM2D(nb_filter=32, nb_row=3, nb_col=3,
                   border_mode='same', return_sequences=True)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(TimeDistributed(ConvLSTM2D(nb_filter=64, nb_row=3, nb_col=3,
                   border_mode='same', return_sequences=True)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(TimeDistributed(Deconvolution2D(128, 5, 5,border_mode='same', output_shape=(None,57, 57, 128), subsample = (2,2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Deconvolution2D(1, 11, 11,border_mode='same', output_shape=(None,227, 227, 1), subsample = (4,4))))


model.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
model.fit(The_data,The_data, batch_size=5,nb_epoch=1)
model.summary()
```

---

I`m trying to read some images and do some preprocessing to them and then apply (A) 2 convolution layers  , (B) three ConvLSTM layers , and (C) 2 Deconvolution layers.

I'm trying to implement the algorithm used in this research [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.01546)
but I see that each of the `layers(conv,deconv,convlstm)` requires something different, i have searched and know that `convlstm` need 5-dim inputs (number of frames) but how to change input shape for it since it is not the first layer in the model.

[overview of algorithm here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMXsi.png)

I have three main questions here :

1- The Convultion2d throw that error

> Error when checking model target: expected convolution2d_2 to have
>   shape (None, 26, 26, 64)`but got array with shape`(250, 227, 227,
>   1)`

2- I have comment ConvLSTM2D because it throw that error

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer convlstm2d_1: expected
>   ndim=5, found ndim=4

and i have also comment Deconvolution because i dont know what output_shape is supposed to be.
I know at the end I should have the input images reconstructed.

3- In `model.fit` , i have no labeled data since I`m doing unsupervised learning , should I leave it that way or what ?

Comment: You need to provide a `video` data but it seems that you are providing an imagery data. Could you describe your data in more details?

Comment: i have a video of dimension 320*240 , i have cut it into frames(images) and put them in 'save' directory and resize them to 227*277 like the paper suggested and have convert them to array for convolution layer (for model.fit) , but it doesn't work.

Comment: But you need your array to be `5-dim` with shape `(nb_of_videos, frames, width, height, channel)`. This is causing problems with `ConvLSTM`s

Comment: you are right with this , but the convLSTM is not the first layer , so can i put input shape to it as well , i want convLSTM layer to take it's input from the second Convolution layer. also when i comment convlstm , the convolution layer still gives me error (the title of my problem)

Comment: Yes - in this case you need to use a `TimeDistributed` wrapper which is applying a layer to each element in a sequence. The same apply to a `deconvolution` layers.

Comment: but why then convolution layer throw that error ? are the data shape consistent with input shape ? or is there something wrong ?.
also i will try TimeDistributed in convLSTM and deconv and see what happen.

Comment: You need to add `border_mode='same'` to both `conv` and `deconv` layers.

Comment: Trying to apply only 2 conv layers but still :
ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected convolution2d_2 to have shape (None, 29, 29, 64) but got array with shape (250, 227, 227, 1)

Comment: Have you uncommented a `deconv` part?

Comment: And - please - add your `model.summary()` after you uncomment `deconv` to your question.

Comment: I have done that , and now i get another new error : IndexError: tuple index out of range
i will edit my code to see my changes.

Comment: the error due to Deconv line 
File "mody.py", line 70, in <module>
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Deconvolution2D(128, 5, 5,border_mode='same', output_shape=(10, 1, 55, 55), subsample = (2,2))))

Comment: Try changing this lines to: `model.add(TimeDistributed(Deconvolution2D(128, 5, 5,border_mode='same', output_shape=(57, 57, 128), subsample = (2,2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Deconvolution2D(1, 11, 11,border_mode='same', output_shape=(1, 227, 227), subsample = (4,4))))`

Comment: Unfortunately still the same error
 IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: Ahh - I forgot - check this:  `model.add(TimeDistributed(Deconvolution2D(128, 5, 5,border_mode='same', output_shape=(57, 57, 128), subsample = (2,2)))) model.add(TimeDistributed(Deconvolution2D(1, 11, 11,border_mode='same', output_shape=(227, 227, 1), subsample = (4,4))))`

Comment: Again, same error.

Comment: From the same layer?

Comment: Yes. but here's is what i have done after that , i have remove TimeDistributed and add None as first element to output_shape in deconv layers and the code runs !

Comment: But why haven't you add `TimeDistributed` to `conv` layers? Maybe this caused problems?

Comment: It gives this error :
ValueError: The first layer in a Sequential model must get an `input_shape` or `batch_input_shape` argument.

Comment: Try `model.add(Convolution2D(128, 11, 11 , border_mode='same', subsample = (4,4)), input_shape=(video_len, 227, 227, 1))` where `video_len` is a number of frames in your video.

Comment: Do i put TimeDistributed in convolution layers or not ?

Comment: Yes, sorry- so many comments. `model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(128, 11, 11 , border_mode='same', subsample = (4,4)), input_shape=(video_len, 227, 227, 1))`. You should also add `TimeDistributed` to other `convs`

Comment: Now TimeDistributed in Deconvolution2D complains that output_shape must have shape (4,), got (3,) when i remove the None , when i add it the problem go to the first conv layer 
expected timedistributed_input_1 to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (250, 227, 227, 1).

I dont have a video , i have convert the video to 250 frame , the research paper make the model train on a sequence of 10 frames at a time. so i guess my video_len = 10

Comment: You need to change your data to appropriate shape. Now you have 250 frames with width and height equal to 227 and with 1 channel. You could try to set up `TimeDistributed` and feed `X.reshape(10, 25, 227, 227, 1)` instead of `X`.

Comment: Thank you , it did work. Now the final problem , when i merge the 3 convLSTM layers i get that old error again
IndexError: tuple index out of range
and the error refers to first ConvLSTM2D
i will update the code again.

Comment: Do not use `TimeDistributed` with `ConvLstm`

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and patience , the code runs like magic.

Comment: Can I form the answer now with all the details?

Comment: Please, go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems lied in:

1. Wrong `input_shape` - data should be cropped to a video `5-d` format. It was done be `reshaping` and cropping.
2. Adding `TimeDistributed` to `conv` and `deconv` layers.
3. Changing a `deconv` output shape to appropriate values.
4. Changing `border_mode` to `same`.

All other details might be found in comments under the question.